# Rails ActiveRecord - Uniqueness and Lookup on Array Attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, serialization, associations

Good morning,

I have a Rails model in which I’m currently serializing an array of information.  Two things are important to me:

1. I want to be able to ensure that this is unique (i.e. can’t have two models with the same array)
2. I want to be able to search existing models for this hash (in a type of find_or_create_by method).

This model describes a “portfolio” – i.e. a group of stock or bonds.  The array is the description of what securities are inside the portfolio, and in what weights.  I also have a second model, which is a group of portfolios (lets call it a “Portcollection” to keep things simple).  A collection has many portfolios, and a portfolio can be in many collections.  In other words:

```
class Portfolio
  serialize :weights
  has_and_belongs_to_many :portcollections

class Portcollection
  has_and_belongs_to_many :portfolios
```

When I am generating a “portcollection” I need to build a bunch of portfolios, which I do programmatically (implementation not important).  Building a portfolio is an expensive operation, so I’m trying to check for the existence of one first.  I thought I could do this via find_or_create_by, but wasn’t having much luck.  This is my current solution:

```
Class Portcollection
  before_save :build_portfolios

  def build_portfolios
    ……
    proposed_weights = ……
    yml =proposed_weights.to_yaml
    if port = Portfolio.find_by_weights(yml)
      self.portfolios << port
    else
      self.portfolios << Portfolio.create!(:weights => proposed_weights)
    end
    ……..
end
```

This does work, but it is quite slow.  I have a feeling this is because I’m converting stuff to YAML each time it runs when I try to check for an existing portfolio (this is running probably millions of times), and I’m searching for a string, as opposed to an integer. I do have an index on this column though.

Is there a better way to do this?  A few thoughts had crossed my mind:

- Calculate an MD5 hash of the “weights” array, and save to a database column.  I’ll still have to calculate this hash each time I want to search for an array, but I have a gut feeling this would be easier for the database to index & search?
- Work on moving from has_and_belongs_to_many to a has_many => through, and store the array information as database columns.  That way I could try to sort out a database query that could check for the uniqueness, without any YAML or serialization…

i.e. something like :

```
class Portfolio
  has_many :portcollections, :through => security_weights

class Portcollections
  has_many :portfolios, :through => security_weights

SECURITY_WEIGHTS
id     portfolio_id      portcollection_id     weight_of_GOOG  weight_of_APPLE ……
1           14                   15                   0.4           0.3
```

In case it is important, the “weights” array would look like this:

```
[ [‘GOOG’, 0.4] , [‘AAPL’, 0.3] , [‘GE’, 0.3] ]
```

Any help would be appreciated.  Please keep in mind I'm quite an amateur - programming is just a hobby for me!  Please excuse me if I'm doing anything really hacky or missing something obvious....

Thanks!

**UPDATE 1**

I've done some research into the Rails 3.2 "store" method, but that doesn't seem to be the answer either... It just stores objects as JSON, which gives me the same lack of searchability I have now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think storing a separate hash in it's own column is the only way to do this efficiently.  You are using serialization or a key/value store that is designed to not be easily searchable.

Just make sure you consider sorting on your values before hashing them, other wise you could have the same content but differing hashes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Joel!  I was afraid this would be the answer... When you say "store a separate hash in its own column" I thought that this was what serialization does.  Did you mean store the hash attributes EACH in their own column?  Would the join model (as described) be a good place for these to live?

Comment: I would add another column in the same model as your key/value store.  Use a MD5 hash calculated from the values you store in the key/value to query against. Rails is doing some "magic" with the key/value store, I wouldn't plan around it in case there are some changes in future versions of rails.